# Is Dart/Flutter has a listener function?

Tags: dart

The listener function can listen to any parameter type(not only listener type). This has nothing related to widgets (this should work successfully in https://dartpad.dev without using the flutter).

ex.

```
int a = 0;
listener((a>0)=>print("A = $a"));
a= 1; //A = 1
a= -1; //
a= 2; //A = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic method is to create the function for updating the parameter that you want to add to the listener.

```
void test() {
  int a = 0;
  void updateA(newA) {
    if(newA is! int) return;
    a = newA;
    if (a > 0) print("A = $a");
  }
  updateA(1);
  updateA(-1);
  updateA(2);
}
```

A better way is to create parameters with class.

```
void main() {
  ParameterWithListener a = ParameterWithListener(data: 0);
  a.listener = () {
    if (a.data is int && a.data > 0) print("A = ${a.data}");
  };
  a.update(1);
  a.update(-1);
  a.update(2);
}

class ParameterWithListener {
  ParameterWithListener({this.data, this.listener});

  dynamic data;
  Function()? listener;

  Future update(data) async {
    this.data = data;
    if (listener is Function()) await listener!();
  }
}
```

result:

```
A = 1
A = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ValueNotifier` for this. It's a `ChangeNotifier` that is triggered when the value is replaced with something that is not equal to the old value as evaluated by the equality operator `==`.

[Here](https://medium.com/swlh/use-valuenotifier-like-pro-6441d9ddad05) is a nice tutorial about this approach.

Comment: Can it use without related to the widget?